# Prolog: In a list, finding the element after a given element

Tags: list, prolog

I recently began programming in Prolog and am currently trying to create rules that find the element after a given element in a list. For example, I want `find(2,X,[1,2,3,4]).` to result in `3`.

My attempt so far:

```
find(X,Y,[X,Y|Tail]):-
   !.
find(X,Y,[_|Tail]):-
   find(X,Y,Tail).
```

Comment: Your code worked fine when I tried it. What's not working for you?

Comment: Clarification 1: By deterministic I mean that no unnecessary choice point is left open. There are, indeed, still situations which require choice points like  `find(X,Y,X)`. There should really be a notion for this.

Answer (score 6):

Let's use `if_/3` and `(=)/3` (a.k.a. `equal_truth/3`), as defined by @false in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27358600/4609915)!

So here comes the new, **logically pure** `find/3`:

```
find(E0,E1,[X|Xs]) :-
   member_next_prev_list(E0,E1,X,Xs).

member_next_prev_list(E0,E1,X0,[X1|Xs]) :-
   if_(X0=E0, X1=E1, member_next_prev_list(E0,E1,X1,Xs)).
```

Let's run the queries mentioned by the OP / by other answers / by some comments:

```
?- find(a,X,[a,a,b]).
X = a.                      % succeeds deterministically
?- find(a,X,[a,Y,b]).
X = Y.                      % succeeds deterministically
?- find(a,b,[a,a,b]).
false.                      % fails

?- find(a,X,[a,a,b,c]).
X = a.                      % succeeds deterministically
?- find(b,X,[a,a,b,c]).
X = c.                      % succeeds deterministically
```

Now to something a *little* more general:

```
?- find(X,Y,[a,a,b,c]).
X = a, Y = a ;
X = b, Y = c ;
false.
```

What about the **most general query**? As the code is **pure**, we get **logically sound** answers:

```
?- find(X,Y,List).
List = [            X,Y|_Z] ;
List = [_A,         X,Y|_Z], dif(_A,X) ;
List = [_A,_B,      X,Y|_Z], dif(_A,X), dif(_B,X) ;
List = [_A,_B,_C,   X,Y|_Z], dif(_A,X), dif(_B,X), dif(_C,X) ;
List = [_A,_B,_C,_D,X,Y|_Z], dif(_A,X), dif(_B,X), dif(_C,X), dif(_D,X) ...
```

---

#### Edit 2015-05-06

Here's a more concise variant, unimaginatively called `findB/3`:

```
findB(E0,E1,[X0,X1|Xs]) :-
   if_(X0=E0, X1=E1, findB(E0,E1,[X1|Xs])).
```

Like `find/3`, `findB/3` is efficient in the sense of not leaving useless choicepoints behind, but it has higher memory use.

`findC/3` tries to reduce the memory use by hoisting the common expression `[X1|Xs]`:

```
findC(E0,E1,[X0|XXs]) :-
   XXs = [X1|_],
   if_(X0=E0, X1=E1, findC(E0,E1,XXs)).
```

Comment: Isn't there a more compact or reusable way to express this?

Comment: Hard to tell what the actual abstraction in between should be, but the current approach does not yield any reusable elements.

Comment: Yes, indeed. This very predicate.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a version w/o the cut:

```
find(X,Y,[X,Y|_]).
find(X,Y,[Z|Tail]) :- 
    X\=Z, find(X,Y,Tail).
```

Comment: Counterexample: `find(a,b,[a,a,b])` should succeed, but your definition fails.

Comment: Correction: this counterexample is not OK. In the sense of the original question, it really should fail here ...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a pure version:

```
find(X,Y, [X,Y|_]).
find(X,Y, [X0,Y0|Xs]) :-
   dif(X+X0,Y+Y0),
   find(X,Y, [Y0|Xs]).
```

I'd rather would like to have a deterministic version, and also a pure DCG version would be cool!

Comment: How should a deterministic version handle `find(a,X,[a,a,b])`?

Comment: (in my sense) it should find both answers - but (now I realize) - in the original sense, it should be *only* `X = a`. Touché.